# In Java, The implementation of the service layer in a three-tier architecture

Tags: java, service, business-logic

I have a question on the service layer, the controller calls the service layer to complete the business logic, service usually have two ways to represent business results, one return value, the second throws an exception. I would like to know the advantages and disadvantages of the two methods,You are in the process of development is often used in what way, give your advice. the following is part of the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)  
@ResponseBody  
public ResultDto login(String username, String password) {

    ResultDto result = loginService.login(username, password);

    return ResultDto;
}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public void login(String username, String password, HttpSession session) {

    // service method define：User login(String, String) throws Exception;
    try {
        User user = loginService.login(username, password);
        // save user to session scope
    } catch(Exception exception) {
        // business logic faild
    }

}
```

Comment: There's not really a question here. Exceptions are used when ordinary processing cannot be completed due to some *exceptional* circumstance, which you would define. Generally speaking, failing to log in would be an exception of some sort. Note that it's unwise to write the security code yourself if you don't have to, and seeing what Spring Security and Shiro do might be instructive.

Comment: It's mostly a matter of flavour, same as with a repository, do you throw a UserNotFoundException or do you just return null or an Optional; the most important part is to keep it in line. People who like Exceptions will say it is more declarative, descriptive and people who don't like Exceptions will say it's bloated, uses too many resources, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is not a positive problem, but this problem bothers me a long time, I English is not very good, so I do not understand chrylis's answer, Nick Vanderhoven's answer is my previous practice, there is a very good "The most important part is to keep it in line.",  Can you explain in more detail the difference between the two ways?